# How to check user certificates file format in order to install them on Android phone

Tags: android, openssl, pem, pkcs#12

I am setting up a freeradius instance for multiple Android end-devices authentication with EAP-TLS.

I first test it with an embedded linux device and the setup works.

The first step is to make it works with one android device.

So I use the freeradius cert Makefile to generate my certs and keys (for client, server and CA).
Extract :

```
######################################################################
#
#  Create a new client certificate, signed by the the above server
#  certificate.
#
######################################################################
client.csr client.key: client.cnf
    $(OPENSSL) req -new  -out client.csr -keyout client.key -config ./client.cnf
    chmod g+r client.key

client.crt: ca.key ca.pem client.csr
    $(OPENSSL) ca -batch -keyfile ca.key -cert ca.pem -in client.csr -key $(PASSWORD_CA) -out client.crt -extensions xpclient_ext -extfile xpextensions -config ./client.cnf

client.p12: client.crt
    $(OPENSSL) pkcs12 -legacy -export -in client.crt -inkey client.key -out client.p12  -passin pass:$(PASSWORD_CLIENT) -passout pass:$(PASSWORD_CLIENT)
    chmod g+r client.p12
    cp client.p12 $(USER_NAME).p12

client.pem: client.p12
    $(OPENSSL) pkcs12 -legacy -in client.p12 -out client.pem -passin pass:$(PASSWORD_CLIENT) -passout pass:$(PASSWORD_CLIENT)
    chmod g+r client.pem
    cp client.pem $(USER_NAME).pem

.PHONY: client.vrfy
client.vrfy: ca.pem client.pem
    c_rehash .
    $(OPENSSL) verify -CApath . client.pem
```

I have upload to my Android device the following files :

- client.p12
- client.pem
- client.crt

The openssl version to generate the certificates is :

```
OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022)
```

I encounter multiple problems to install the user certificates file :

- While installing the p12 file, I first get this warning from logcat :

> W CredentialHelper: java.io.IOException: exception decrypting data -
> java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: 1.2.840.113549.1.5.12
> SecretKeyFactory not available

So I ask the openssl user mailing list, and they answer me that I must use the "-legacy" option in openssl pkcs12 command.
I fix it, and regenarate the keys.

- Then I installed my new "legacy" p12 file and I get this from logcat when I want to use it:

> wpa_supplicant: TLS - SSL error: error:0900006e:PEM
> routines:OPENSSL_internal:NO_START_LINE

As it comes from a PEM Android module I wanted to try installing my client.pem file and I get this error :

> W CredentialHelper: parseCert():
> java.security.cert.CertificateException:
> com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory$ParsingException:
> com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory$ParsingException:
> java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0c0000be:ASN.1 encoding
> routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_TAG

I am thinking that it comes from a format error in the crt file but how can I obtain more details ?

Comment: I also have this issue and posted a [similar question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/250728/how-should-a-user-certificate-be-formatted-so-that-it-can-be-used-for-mtls-on-a) on android enthusiasts.  I also posted on openssl-users, but still no answers.  I'm wondering if it's an issue with Conscrypt, and may post on that mailing list next.

Comment: Yes I've seen your post. My Android test phones do not use Conscrypt as far as I know.

Comment: Conscrypt is a JSP used by CredentialHandler - the java app that is called by settings when installing a certificate on an android phone.  Note the "com.android.org.conscrypt...." in your error message.